# Why Multiple connections happening for bulk update in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb

I am new to mongodb.I established one time connection to mongodb. I have huge data to update mongodb. So i am iterating every thousand records and upserting in to db. When i see the status, showing 400 connections. After upserting records also, those connections are not closing. Can you please tell me why it is creating so many connections?

**Code:**

`var data = [] //assume here is 4000000 records are there.`

`var batchData = [];`

`for(var i in data){`

`if(i/1000 == 0){`

`db.somecollection.insertMany(batchData);`

`batchData = [];`

`}`
`else{`

`batchData.push(data[i]);`

`}}`

Comment: Please post the code you use to connect to MongoDB.

Comment: @KevinAdistambha : code snippet provided. kindly look into it.

Comment: the code looks fine. How did you know it was creating many connections? What status do you see?

Comment: Also could you post the whole code with the connection part?